# Remove white space between header and body

Tags: css

I've tried to remove the white space between the header and body but can't get it to work. I've included a snippet that shows my code. anyone knows how to sort this?

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: #345cd7;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.top-box {
    background-color: #345cd7;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="images/white.svg" id="logo" />
</header>
    <div class="top-box">
        <h1>Welcome to</h1>
        <h2>Welcome to the family. Download one of the apps and get making them calls!</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why on Earth is your `header` tag outside of `body` tag?

Comment: add `position: absolute; width: 100%;` to `.top-box`

Comment: `h1` naturally has margin on it, so if you do not remove it, it can cause a [collapsing margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) effect putting the margin onto the parent (which is what is causing your gap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `margin:0` in your h1 tag.

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: #345cd7;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.top-box {
    background-color: #345cd7;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.top-box h1{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="images/white.svg" id="logo" />
</header>
<body>
    <div class="top-box">
        <h1>Welcome to</h1>
        <h2>Welcome to the family. Download one of the apps and get making them calls!</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i was felt in same situation, there was a white space between nav_bar and carousel and i did almost every thing, by your answer i got that i have to set margin to carousel not to the header. thanks for your valuable answer. i really appericiate your help. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just use the universal selector:

```
*{ margin: 0%; }
```

source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/u/universal/

Answer (score 1):

`h1` tag by default has a margin. So just removing that margin, in this case top, will do the work

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #345cd7;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-box {
  background-color: #345cd7;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/white.svg" id="logo" />
</header>
<div class="top-box">
  <h1>Welcome to</h1>
  <h2>Welcome to the family. Download one of the apps and get making them calls!</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your header inside the body:

```
<body>

  <header>
    <img src="images/white.svg" id="logo" />
  </header>

  <div class="top-box">
    <h1>Welcome to</h1>
    <h2>Welcome to the family. Download one of the apps and get making them calls!</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Make sure you 0 out any padding and margin on the header

Comment: I've changed that, and it still did that but I've got a working answer already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden` for the header stylesheet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering it is really useful to explain why someone should use the code you suggest and how you think it will help to solve their problem. That way they and others can learn from the solution rather than blindly copy and paste it.